# Can a component have different templates to switch to based on a parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-components

**Situation**

I need to write a component that loads content onto the page. The content(JSON array with objects) is loaded from a database. Two components must create one page. The component tree would look like this.

```
DataList - receives full JSON object
  DataListItem - must display the first object
  DataListItem - must display the second object
  DataListItem - and so on
```

The `DataListItem` can display the content in multiple ways. This is why it needs multiple templates.

I do not want to drop everything in one HTML file, add a `ngSwitch` directive and call it a day. I also do not want to make a component for every template. I have about 72 templates. I just want multiple HTML files that I can load into the `DataListItem` component.

---

**How I try to solve this**

Right now I'm trying to do an HTTP request to get the template and that seems to work.

But `{{ data.contentId }}` doesn't seem to bind. It just displays the binding as plain text on the page. [Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQyjM.png)

I want to know how I can accomplish this, or if it is even possible.

Thanks in advance ;)

---

**Edit**

I'm just going to the root of this question. Is it possible to load different templates in a component? A parameter provided by the parent component is supposed to tell what type of template should be chosen.

Sorry, my brain does not work anymore and I have to much code to just dump it on plunker. It also is connected to an API so you would not even be able to load data.

Comment: Perhaps - this article will guide you to achieve that - https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/10/01/angular-template-ref-dynamic-scoping-custom-templates/

Comment: If you could create a plunkr we could help you a lot better and maybe you can even understand your problem yourself

Comment: To to get help with this issue- add some code from your parent and child components

Comment: You can have multiple templates in a component - there are ways to get it working.  However, I don't think you can download templates from API and use it.

Comment: Can I have multiple templates in each there own file? because thats what my problem is. I have a lot of templates for one component and I don't want to make one huge html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding [p3x-angular-compile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p3x-angular-compile) which can compile the HTML you pass through. I request that HTML still with HTTP. This way I can have multiple files that contain the templates I want to use.

> just for the person with the same problem. You need Nodejs 10.5.0+ for this plugin to work

anyway, thanks for the help.